# Distinguish between null and missing field when reading json into pyspark dataframe

Tags: json, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, null

I'm reading in a set of jsonl files with a schema to a dataframe:

```py
df = spark.read.option("mode", "FAILFAST").json(
    f"{base_input_uri}/*.jsonl*", schema)
```

and I want to distinguish between fields that are present in the jsonl with an explicit value of `null` (which I want to maintain as `null` in the dataframe) and fields that are missing entirely from a record. At the moment, both become `None` in the dataframe, and in this case, we need to know which are coming in explicitly as `null`s.

I've tried setting `spark.sql.jsonGenerator.ignoreNullFields` to `false` in the spark configuration to no avail.

I also tried:

```py
df = spark.read.option("mode", "FAILFAST").json(
    f"{base_input_uri}/*.jsonl*", schema, ignoreNullFields=False)
```

but that resulted in

```
TypeError: DataFrameReader.json() got an unexpected keyword argument 'ignoreNullFields'
```

Comment: You are getting the error because the correct way to set it is `.option("ignoreNullFields","false)`. But this is used only for write not read so it's not what you need. I think there is no direct way to do this. Might have to read the file and convert the explicit nulls to a value like `99999` then use `.json()` to read.. Then you will know `99999` are explicit nulls and `null` is missing keys.